# Goland Cannot convert expression of type string to type []byte

Tags: goland

I am using Goland for golang code and the convert check seems working with a bug while I transfer a "string" type to a "[]byte" type.

It can be complied correctly with a expecting result, but the tip still shows in the editor. Maybe there is something wrong in my setting? Anyone can help me?

```
package main

import (
  "crypto/sha1"
  "encoding/hex"
  "fmt"
)

func Sha1(data string) string {
  encrypts := sha1.New()
  encrypts.Write([]byte(data)) // Cannot convert expression of type string to type []byte
  return hex.EncodeToString(encrypts.Sum([]byte("")))
}

func main() {
  fmt.Println(Sha1("123456"))
}
```

[Here is my Goland editor screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkSSj.png)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot replicate this. We need more details to be able to help you. Please open an issue on our tracker and follow the instructions there in the issue template on what data to provide in order to help investigate the issue youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go

Comment: Sorry I can’t reproduce your error with [ go version go1.11.2 darwin/amd64, GoLand 2018.3, by default setting]

Comment: @NajlaBioinfo I asked my classmates to check their GoLand only find the error on my own Mac. Thanks for your information, I'll open an issue on Jetbrains' website, so I can find out what's wrong with my IDE.  sad :(

Comment: @dlsniper Sorry for replying you so late. I had opened an issue on your link at November 15th, and here is the link [https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-6450](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-6450). Please contact me if you need any more informations. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I posted an issue on [Jetbrains track](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues), and got replied. Only to find that my GoLand inspector works well if I pasted the same code in a brand new project. So maybe there is something wrong in my "old" project, and I will post more information if I find what's wrong in my "odd" project.